# How to get data from table and define the geometry on the same query?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, sql, query, database

My team is using DB2 database and I have to create and publish a map service in ArcGIS using one of the tables. The table has the XYZ column but no SRID defined in the table or database. The DB2 spatial extender is installed.

I tried to import using the new query layer but the geometry cannot be defined and I end up with an "Event table" layer which cannot be published.

I guess that there is a way to define the geometry via the query, but I am not sure how to do so. So, the question is: **how can I retrieve data from table (X,Y,Z) and define the geometry on the same query?**

Comment: What have you tried? You're not going to find a ton of DB2 users here, so you'll need to provide more information. Please [Edit] the question to specify whether you have the Esri DB2 extender installed, what coordinate reference the data uses, and how you have attempted to accomplish your goal. I'd recommend creating a new table with an additional geometry column, then  using `INSERT ... SELECT` to populate the new table.

Comment: Inserting a geometry column is not an option in my case. But it would have been the first thing to test otherwise!

Comment: You'll pay a usurous price for not having the geometry, and its index, with every spatial query.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for is the using the ST_GeomFromText function as explained in the IBM docs. For future reference check link below: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/rsbp4080.html

More precisely the part of the query is:

```
db2gse.ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || X || ' ' || Y || ')', WKID)
```

where X and Y are the coordinate columns and WKID is the EPSG code of the coordinate system that you would like to apply.